# Why doesn't iTunes backup every time I charge my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, backup, charging

I read years ago when they introduced wireless syncing with iTunes, that they would backup my phone every time I would charge my phone wirelessly. I waited years and to this day this still doesn't work properly. It seems to want to backup randomly. I charge my phone every night, but my latest backup is always more than a week ago.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you pulled up you device in iTunes, and made sure "Sync Wirelessly" is still checked?

Comment: This should be somewhat easy to poke at. You can shut off iTunes for a day or two and watch what happens when the iPhone is on the WiFi and charging and you start iTunes. Then wait to see if a sync starts. If not, put the device in AirPlane mode - wait and then have it join the network. Once you determine the trigger that starts a wireless sync, you can theorize about why it's not happening regularly.

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt back up everytime you charge it. Wireless syncing just means you dont need the data transfer cable, that you can do it "over the air", so the week old back ups are the legit ones